# How should I pass data in my render method with React/redux

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I'm trying to adapt the following react bar chart to my react/redux project : http://codepen.io/clindsey/collab/RRZBQm/. Most of the code is ok for me however I don't really understand the rendering part :

```
setTimeout(() => {
  const data = {'alpha': 82, 'bravo': 20, 'charlie': 68};
  const size = [480, 320];
  const margins = [40, 40, 40, 40];
  ReactDOM.render(
    <BarChart {...{data, margins, size}} />
  , document.getElementById('js-app'));
}, 0);
```

Why in this example, "const" are passed in ReactDOM.render function through the BarChart element ?

When adapting this to my local project I've got the following code in my container :

```
    const App = () => (

      <div>
        <Component1 />
        <Component2 />
        <BarChart />
      </div>
    );

    export default App;
```

then I use `mapStateToProps` function to pass `const data`, `const size` and `const margins`, like this :

```
const data = {'alpha': 82, 'bravo': 20, 'charlie': 68};
const size = [480, 320];
const margins = [40, 40, 40, 40];

     function mapStateToProps(state) {
        return {
            data: data,
            size: size,
            margins: margins,
                  };
                };
```

It's working fine but I didn't really understand what I'm doing. Not sure if It's good practice or it it's heaven make sense.

Thanks.

Comment: What specfically don't you understand? `const` is just a way of declaring variables that won't be re-assigned.

Comment: So passing `const` into `mapStateToProps()` like the way I did it is totally ok ?

Comment: it is OKAY but, that's not what mapStateToProps was made for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole idea of mapStateToProps is to link your Redux store to your (in your case) React Components. Typically you'd use it like this

```
function mapStateToProps(state){
    return {
        propertyOne: state.myPropertyOne, //state.myPropertyOne comes from your redux store, when you return this object, your component gets this object
        propertyTwo: state.myPropertyTwo
    };
}
```

You didn't have to pass your `const` variables into the function for it to work. If they were in that file you could have just used them directly.

Seems to work just fine 
https://jsfiddle.net/julianljk/qkjkqf6q/

Comment: Ok thanks. I don't know why but It seems cleaner to me to have everything in my State/Props.

Comment: +1, `mapStateToProps` should be used for... mapping _state_ to props, not constants. Better to put the `const` definitions inside of the `render()` function of the parent component.

Comment: and there's nothing wrong with it, its just not convention. Also, accessing those things become longer. Instead of lets say `let a = data`, you'll need to do `let a = this.props.data` in your React lifecycle methods